Automatically configuring a new driver in DBeaver Community Edition
We would like to add a new driver to the DBeaver's of each of our 100+ Windows users (Community Edition).
We can easily create an installer that drops the binaries locally, but in order to configure the driver in DBeaver, so far the only option seems to involve editing the drivers.xml file under the DBeaver workspace folder.
Is there a way to add the driver without editing existing files, e.g. by dropping files under the DBeaver workspace folder (which is actually a supported way for adding new connections)?
